# Не передается глобальная переменная в js

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться - нужно из скрипта передать переменную в другой скрипт.
Пробую сделать так:
Задаю глобальную переменную

```
var razmerVes = "";
```

по клику присваю переменной новое значение

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#el_<?=$arOneValue?>").click(function() {
        razmerVes = "<?=$x?>";
    });
});
```

Далее хочу получить ее в другом скрипте

```
pec_goods[0] = window.razmerVes; // Ширина/Длина/Высота/Объем/Вес
```

Но в переменной `razmerVes` пусто.

Comment: Скрипт в которм хочу получить значение находится чуть ниже по коду на этой же странице

Comment: Нужно убрать `var` и объявить также `window.razmerVes = "";`

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Не передается и все.

Comment: Не трогайте объект window, к вашей программе он никакого отношения не имеет. Заведите свой объект, в своем scope и используйте его.

Comment: window.razmerVes != razmerVes

Comment: @ilyaplot, тут могут быть варианты

Answer (score 4):

Содержимое функции, переданной в качестве аргумента `$(document).ready` выполняется **асинхронно**. Это значит, что ваша переменная получает *правильное* значение, но в неправильный момент времени. Иными словами, вы скорее всего используете переменную `razmerVes` *до* того, как присваиваете ей значение.

Если вы так хотите асинхронно передавать данные через глобальную переменную, используйте *Обещания* (Promises):

```
window.razmerVes = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#target_el").click(function() {
            // Возвращаем значение через Обещание.
            resolve('foo bar baz');
        });
    });
});
```

Теперь, в скрипте, где вам нужно получить значение `razmerVes` можно сделать следующее:

```
window.razmerVes.then(function(value) {
    // Выведет "foo bar baz"
    alert(value);
});
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb184tsd/) на JSFiddle.

Однако, что-то мне подсказывает, что вам вовсе не нужно работать с переменной `razmerVes` в асинхронной манере. Если это так, то вы можете вынести установку значения переменной из функции:

```
window.razmerVes = "<?=$x?>";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#el_<?=$arOneValue?>").click(function() {
        // Другие асинхронные действия
    });
});
```

**Замечание:**

Вообще, за глобальные переменные надо бить по рукам. Ситуации, когда их действительно нужно использовать можно пересчитать по пальцам одной руки, и ваш случай не похож на одину из таких.

Comment: Чтобы бить по рукам, достаточно написать `'use strict';`.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутые ответы. НО как по другому получить, без объявления переменной глобальной получить значение переменной в другом месте кода?

Comment: @YuraIvanov, я скорее об административных, а не о технических мерах

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных - это ошибка, use strict помогает увидеть эту ошибку невооруженным глазом. Тем временем, хранение каких-то своих данных в системных объектах window, document и проч - это за гранью зла, тут да только административные меры.

Comment: @DENVOL, увы, мне это не интересно. Попробуйте обратиться на биржу фрилансеров. Если же у вас есть **конкретные** вопросы, можете смело задавать их на ru.SO (разумеется в виде новых, отдельных вопросов).

Comment: какже по другому функцию задать. нужно по клику получить значение. Без $(document).ready(function() {
$("#el_<?=$arOneValue?>").click(function() { не работает

Comment: Если так хотите возвращать значения асинхронно - используйте обещания. В ответе я показал, как это можно сделать

Comment: @YuraIvanov, а как _use strict_ помогает увидеть ошибку глобальных переменных?

Comment: @Grundy попробуйте: `'use strict'; a='1';`

Comment: @YuraIvanov, это никак относится к _глобальным_ переменным, это относится к _необъявленным_ переменным, если переменная объявлена выше данный код отлично отработает

Comment: ОК. как заявязять Promise на клик

Comment: @Grundy ТС путает глобальные переменные, объявленные с `var` и *глобальные перменные в контексте window, являющиеся его свойствами*, считая это одним и тем же. Убрав var, как например, советует Doofy, получим либо ошибку при use strict, либо административное наказание, которое предлагает Dmitriy Simushev.

Comment: @DENVOL, обновил ответ

Comment: пробую так  $("#el_<?=$arOneValue?>").click(function () {
 
      razmerVes = "<?=$razm?>";
   
   //alert(razmerVes);
      });
В alert переменная есть при клике получаю. дальше пусто

Comment: @DENVOL,  в ответе я показал, как использовать _Обещания_. Код, что вы привели их не использует. Похоже, я зря тратил время на развернутый ответ.

Comment: Написал по вашему. 
 window.razmerVes = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#el_<?=$arOneValue?>").click(function() {
            // Возвращаем значение через Обещание.
            resolve('<?=$razm?>');
        });
    });
});


window.razmerVes.then(function(value) {
    // Выведет "foo bar baz"
    console.log(value);
});
Ничего не выводит

Comment: @DENVOL, обновил ответ, добавив ссылку на _работающий_ пример кода на JSFiddle. Похоже, ваша проблема где-то еще

Comment: там на самом деле несколько кнопок подаются через массив значений, при таком подходе сработала последняя.